# Matrix Conditions

Tags: linear-algebra

$A_{m \ x \ n}$ is a matrix, and $x, z \in \mathbb{R}^n$

Under what conditions on A ensures that for any $x$ there also exists $z \ne x$ such that $Az = Ax$

I'm trying to get my head around how to approach this. I was thinking along the lines of there must be two solutions to $Ay = b$?

Comment: Begin by reviewing this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(linear_algebra)

Comment: What are $A$ and $x$? A matrix (of what sort of entries?), and a vector? You should really say what your notation means, since it's not universal.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $Ae_i$ is the $i$th column of matrix $A$, where $e_i$ is the $i$th standard basis vector, having only one $1$ as its $i$th coordinate, the rest is $0$.

Comment: Hmm, apparently the answer isn't 0. Maybe i've misinterpreted my problem set question then? "What conditions are required on A so the following holds: for any y where Ay = b, there also exists Az = b." I thought it would follow that A(y - z) = 0 so it had to be for any Ax = 0. If that makes sense . . .

Comment: You probably aren't asking the question you think you are asking, since the answer is "always, just choose $z=y$".

Comment: Sorry, I'm making a right hash of this. For a z not equal to y.

Comment: I recommend editing the question and asking the question that you mean to ask; you'll get more appropriately directed help that way.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are asking about when does $Av = 0$ for some non-zero vector $v$. Since once such $v$ exists then you can set $z = x + v$ for any $x$ and you will have your $x$ and $z$ satisfying $Ax = Az$ with $x \neq z$. So what does $Av = 0$ for non-zero $v$ tell you about $A$?

Comment: Rank (A) less than n?